# Refactor similar code used by multiple methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, refactoring

I have a situation like this: there are two methods (that i can't change, because they come from an abstract class) **from()** and **to()** that must execute the same code with only a small difference. I created a third method and i used a boolean variable to know which of the two methods called the third. Now, is there a way write this in a cleaner way?

```
protected from(x: any): any[] {
  return this.convertArray(true, x);
}

protected to(y: any): any[] {
  return this.convertArray(false, y);
}

private convertArray(isFrom: boolean, inArray: any[]): any[] {
  const array = [];
  if (this.types.length === 1) {
      // ... some code here ...
      array.push(isFrom ? adapter.from(value) : adapter.to(value));
  } else {
      // ... some code here ...
      array.push(isFrom ? adapter.from(inArray[i]) : adapter.to(inArray[i]));
  }
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few other options:

1. You can use a string for the method name and brackets notation to get the method from `adapter`:

   ```
   private convertArray(isFrom: boolean, inArray: any[]): any[] {
     const array = [];
     const method = isFrom ? "from" : "to";          // ***
     if (this.types.length === 1) {
         // ... some code here ...
         array.push(adapter[method](value));         // ***
     } else {
         // ... some code here ...
         array.push(adapter[method](inArray[i]));    // ***
     }
     return array;
   }
   ```
2. You can use a wrapper function created via `bind` (so that `this` within the call is `adapter`):

   ```
   private convertArray(isFrom: boolean, inArray: any[]): any[] {
     const array = [];
     const method = (isFrom ? adapter.from : adapter.to).bind(adapter); // ***
     if (this.types.length === 1) {
         // ... some code here ...
         array.push(method(value));         // ***
     } else {
         // ... some code here ...
         array.push(method(inArray[i]));    // ***
     }
     return array;
   }
   ```

   or (call it "2(b)") via an arrow function:

   ```
   private convertArray(isFrom: boolean, inArray: any[]): any[] {
     const array = [];
     const op = isFrom ? value => adapter.from(value) // ***
                       : value => adapter.to(value);  // ***
     if (this.types.length === 1) {
         // ... some code here ...
         array.push(op(value));                       // ***
     } else {
         // ... some code here ...
         array.push(op(inArray[i]));                  // ***
     }
     return array;
   }
   ```
3. Or use the method directly via `.call`:

   ```
   private convertArray(isFrom: boolean, inArray: any[]): any[] {
     const array = [];
     const method = isFrom ? adapter.from : adapter.to; // ***
     if (this.types.length === 1) {
         // ... some code here ...
         array.push(method.call(adapter, value));       // ***
     } else {
         // ... some code here ...
         array.push(method.call(adapter, inArray[i]));  // ***
     }
     return array;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, they are all good alternatives. Do you have a favorite one? Just to know.

Comment: @nacho111 - For me, with the information in the question, it's really a toss-up. From one perspective, #1 seems best because it's simple and direct. But I don't like using strings for method names rather than literals (it makes refactoring difficult), which counts against it. I think #2 (or the newly-added 2(a)) may very slightly be my favorite, but nothing against #3 other than `.call` is clunky. #3 has the advantage of not creating functions we can avoid creating. So, yeah, a toss-up. :-)